# How to install pip and python modules with a single batch file?

Tags: python, batch-file

I really don't understand how batch files work. But I made a python script for my father to use in his work. And I thought installing pip and necessary modules with a single batch file would make it a lot easier for him. So how can I do it?

The modules I'm using in script are: xlrd, xlsxwriter and tkinter.

Comment: Did you put the modules in a requirements.txt ?
You can then install all modules with a single pip command :  pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 7):

To make sure your Windows is running pip, download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and place it in the same folder as the .bat file.
You can create a .bat file using a text editor and then changing the extension to .bat

Try this:

```
@echo off


:start
cls

set python_ver=36

python ./get-pip.py

cd \
cd \python%python_ver%\Scripts\
pip install xlrd
pip install XlsxWriter

pause
exit
```

tkinter in already included in Python since 3.1

[Source](https://simply-python.com/2014/03/20/easy-invoke-pip-install-using-batch-commands/)

Comment: Thank you, this has everything I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `requirements.txt` file then use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to download all modules, if you are working on a virtual environment and you only have the modules your project uses, you can use `pip3 freeze >> requirements.txt` This is not a batch file but it will work just fine and it is pretty easy

Answer (score 4):

I think the route you are taking is hard and may create a lot of difficulty for the non-technical person. My advice would be to to consider these alternatives:

1. Create an executable that bundles all requirements up, using something like [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)
2. This may not be very applicable given that you are using tkinter. For non desktop apps, you could make your script a backend and Create a web app using a micro-webframework like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). Host it online on heroku or PythonAnywhere (Both platforms have free plans) and give them the link.

I used to create scripts as a freelancer and my life became easier when I learned to distribute them using those 2 methods.

Comment: I may consider these 2 methods for further scripts but this one will only be used by only one person and I believe he will easily open a batch file. But thanks a lot I will consider these the next time I’m doing something.

Answer (score 2):

To install pip, you can download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run it like that in your batch file (batch file and get-pip.py should be in the same folder) :

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then to install modules, you can create a file requirements.txt (in the same folder) with this content :

```
xlrd
xlsxwriter
tkinter
```

and use this command in your batch file :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The problem is that now you have 3 files, get-pip.py, requirements.txt and the batch file.
If you want to make it easier, you can hide the py & txt file in the properties like that (for Windows) :

[image]

Or you can get rid of requirements.txt by replacing

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

with

```
pip install xlrd
pip install xlsxwriter
pip install tkinter
```

in your batch file.